# How to override stencil component template in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, stenciljs, stencil-component

I use the https://github.com/telekom/scale components library (not writing my own library). All components there were built using Stencil and they can be used without problems.

However, I need to change a Stencil component html a bit and add an additional label for example.

The problem is that I cannot find out how to extend Stencil component and **override its rendering template**.

I know I can just simply reconstruct the template by the sources of `render` method but I hope there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that we have a component with the `bla-bla-tag` selector. There are a couple of options that might be applied depending on your case.

Case 1: Prepend some stuff inside nested component

```html
<bla-bla-tag>
  <span>I want to see it before inner component stuff</span>
</bla-bla-tag>
```

Case 2: Modify DOM

The problem was to wait until inner component fully loads its view.

Fortunately, there was a hook in `HTMLStencilElement` interface: `componentOnReady(): Promise<this>;`.

Stencil docs have the following example:

```js
export class HomeComponent {
  @ViewChild(TestComponent) myTestComponent: ElementRef<TestComponent>;

  async onAction() {
    await this.myTestComponent.nativeElement.testComponentMethod();
  }
}
```

So the end solution for me was to access the stencil component via `ViewChild` and then use the hook from above example.

View:

```html
<scale-text-field
            #input
...
        ></scale-text-field>
```

Component code:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'bla-bla-tag',
    templateUrl: './some.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./some.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class SomeComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('input') textField!: ElementRef<HTMLScaleTextFieldElement>;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.textField.nativeElement.componentOnReady().then(scaleTextField => {
// any dom modifications
        })
    }
}
```

Also, I needed to work with some css classes so to prevent Angular from encapsulating them: `ViewEncapsulation.None`